# Change structure of an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to create multiple bars on a chart and I get the data from an Ajax call.

What I encounter is linked to the format of the array I get.

What I am doing to create the array is :

```
elements = [];

// AJAX request here ($.getJSON(...))

    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        elements.push(value.item1);
    }

// End of $.getJSON
```

When using this method, Highcharts does not work properly, I know I can add the data another way but I would still like to solve this problem.

Here is what happens when I `console.log(elements)` :

```
Array []
​
0: 0
​
1: 0
​
2: 0
​
3: 0
​
4: 0
​
5: 5
​
6: 0
​
length: 7
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

I can get the structure I want by writing `var elements = [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0];`

When I `console.log(elements)` I get this structure :

```
Array(6) [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0 ]
​
0: 0
​
1: 0
​
2: 0
​
3: 0
​
4: 5
​
5: 0
​
length: 6
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

To me both arrays are similar but there's a difference on the first line of the *console.log()*.

I don't really understand what is causing this.

*EDIT:*
After the Ajax and the $.each, I create the chart, but when using an array created with

```
elements.push()
```

the chart is not created.

My problem does not come from the fact that console.log displays different things, it comes from the fact that Highcharts does not "understand" the array I am giving it.

Comment: Have you verified that `value.item1` contains the value you expect it to contain?

Comment: In the first example, you're probably logging the array before it is populated. When you expand the array, it will show the updated array every time because it keeps a reference

Comment: @Vini yes, basically the first console.log is the data I get from the ajax call, the second one is created by me by writing manually the data I get from the AJAX to debug, so the data is the same.

Comment: As @adiga mentioned, you are trying to print the array before it is populated. You can try  populating the array and process it in the `.done` handler/callback. Created a sample jsFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/r6qapug5/2/

Comment: Hi @HectorB, It would be good if you could reproduce the problem in some live example. However, you probably try to create a chart before async data is received. You need to create a chart or update it after the async operation. Please check this simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xb3ksgfh/